# db2, group data so that results can be column names

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a fairly straightforward query that returns a result set, which I want to not only do a group and count by but I want to transform the results into column names as well (this is in db2)

```
    select t1.user,t2.category,t2.color,t2.store_number  
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 
    ON t1.store_number = t2.store_number;
```

that returns:

```
    user | category  |  color  |  store_number
    --------------------------------------------
    12      A           'blue'      123             
    12      A           'blue'      123
    12      A           'blue'      456
    12      A           'blue'      456
    12      A           'blue'      456
    12      A           'blue'      123
    12      A           'blue'      123
    12      A           'blue'      456
    12      A           'blue'      123
    12      A           'blue'      789
```

So that would result in this, technically:

```
    user | store_number | count
    ------------------------------
    12        123           5
    12        456           4
    12        789           1
```

But how can I take the query results and actually turn it into this:

```
    user | 123  |  456  |  789
    ---------------------------
    12      5       4        1
```

So the store number is the column name and the count is the data. How can I properly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DB2 has a pivot function.  You would need to use case statements and aggregation. Something like:

```
    select
    user,
    count (case when store_number = 123 then color else null end) as store_123,
    ...
group by user
```

Comment: This works, though I have an issue. Without my Join I get 4 rows of the data I need, but the join for the store numbers increases it. How can I do this so that I get this count but still only get my 4 rows from the original table?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but try using `count (distinct ...)` instead of just `count`.